# Is there a better way to write an AVG() SQL query for multiple tables (or a way to improve my code)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, average

im kinda new to managing sql queries with big amounts of data and im trying to improve performance on a request.
My issue is that i have multiple tables with different names that have the same structure, so i have to avg the value of temp from all of them to use later.

I'm currently working with this code :

```
//these value changes on each request, here are some examples to help you understand
$ano_desde = 2019; 
$mes_hasta = 4;
$id_t = 1123;
//

for ($ano = $ano_desde; $ano <= $ano_hasta; $ano++) {
            for ($mes = $mes_hasta; $mes <= 12; $mes++) {


                $sql = " SELECT AVG(temp) FROM table".$ano."_".$mes." WHERE id_t = $id_t";

                //HERE I WOULD SEND THE QUERY TO MY DB AND SAVE RESP ON $TEMP

                $temp = queryResp;

                if ($temp != 0) {
                    $temps[] = floatval($temps);
                }
            }
        }
```

This does the work but it comes with a hit on my response of 4 to 5 seconds and i would love to improve it, be it in the php code or in my query.

Thanks in advance, i apologize for any spelling errors as english is not my first language.

Comment: The first thing you should learn is to store the data all in one table, rather than splitting the tables out by year.

Comment: i have no control over the db schema unfortunately and it was made this way

Comment: Do your tables have any relevant indexes?

Comment: not really, no. only relevant index is id_t

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is sql that look something like
It would join all the tables and then do a avg. (if you do it for each table you will get the average of an average.

```
SELECT AVG(temp) from (
SELECT temp FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
UNION ALL
SELECT temp FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
UNION ALL
SELECT temp FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
) a
```

Actually you call also do it like this for better performance

```
SELECT s/c avgtmp from (
SELECT sum(temp) s, count(temp) c FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(temp) s, count(temp) c FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(temp) s, count(temp) c FROM table.ano._mes1 WHERE id_t = id_t
) a
```